# Shouldn't we spell “extrovert” as “extravert”?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, orthography

I saw the spelling ***extrovert*** in a text, but I intuitively felt that the correct spelling is ***extravert***.

I did a little research and read that ***extravert*** is commonly used in scientific/technical literature, while ***extrovert*** is common in non-technical usage.

From what I read, it seems that this is because in 1918 when the word ***extravert*** was becoming more popular and more commonly used outside of technical literature, non-technical people often misspelled it as ***extrovert*** because it was commonly paired with the word ***introvert***.

Am I wrong if I choose to **always** (even in non-technical writing)   spell it ***extravert*** because I think it is the **correct** spelling    and that I think other people are spelling it incorrectly? Or does majority rule and am I wrong to not conform to the majority?

**My question is more about the decision that I need to make** (based on which alternative is right or wrong and why) than about this specific example of ***extrovert*** vs ***extravert***. I've had similar experiences with other spelling and also grammar rule mismatches, so I'd like to be confident in my decisions in those other situations too.

-Does majority rule? Or are they technically wrong?

**If majority does rule, at what point does a misspelling or a grammar error become correct?** 50% saturation? 75%? Does the original simultaneously become incorrect at that point? For the example above, if ***extravert*** is **incorrect** to use in non-technical writing, at what point did it become incorrect? Because at one point it was the only way of spelling it, and was only pushed out of popular use by replication of the misspelled form.

Comment: If you’ve got a dictionary behind you- go for it.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I grabbed the nearest dictionary (Webster's New Collegiate 9th) and couldn't find anything about when a misspelling becomes correct or when the original correct spelling becomes incorrect. Is it somewhere in the pages of text in the front, about the history of the English language and dictionaries? I'm not gonna try and find it there with my weak eyes. More guidance, please. Thanks, @Jim

Comment: @bof I think Jim means that if I have the support of a dictionary that a particular spelling is acceptable then I should feel free to use that spelling however I wish. My issue is that the dictionary I checked shows **extravert** as correct only for technical usage, and **extrovert** as correct for popular/non-technical usage, so I don't really "have that dictionary behind me". However, the dictionary in my mind says **extravert** is always correct and **extrovert** is always incorrect, while the dictionary in this browser puts a red line under **extravert**, indicating that it is incorrect.

Comment: A Scientific American blogger [here](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/beautiful-minds/the-difference-between-extraversion-and-extroversion/) says that in 1918 a certain Phyllis Blanchard wrote a paper in which she translated _extravertierte_ as 'extroversion'. The blogger feels sure this was an error. He notes the modern scientific/popular split between the extra- and extro- usages and claims that the most vociferous champions of extro- are keen Jungians, whereas the extra- users are the present day personality scientists.

Comment: Is it technically wrong to spell "rough" and "laugh" and "though" and "might" with the letters "gh"?

Comment: Don't forget 'through' in the USA.

Comment: In Italian "extrovert" is "estr**o**verso"

Comment: @Mari-LouA The charges of prescriptivism aside, I think there is still a place for promoting proper spelling. As for the first of your examples, some might say that the *ruff* is for the dogs. :)

Comment: While "extraversion" is an option, I'm not sure we can go so far as to say that it getting coined as "extroversion" was wrong, thus resulting in how it's predominantly spelled, since there is well-established and longstanding precedent to use O in English as the linking letter between borrowed root words and/or affices or between root words and/or affices derived from foreign words.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Google Books 
Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=extrovert%2C+extravert&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cextrovert%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cextravert%3B%2Cc0)
,
the spelling with 'o' is preferable.

Though etymologically (according to *EtymologyOnline*) the word was spelt with 'a', the spelling was changed on analogy with 'introvert'.

So they (extrovert - introvert) make a good match.

I think this 100-year-old spelling doesn't need any change. 
Otherwise we must have changed the spelling of such words as ISLAND, DEBT, ADMIRAL, etc.

The choice of the spelling variant depends on the user (like TRAVELER/TRAVELLER, CACTUSES/ CACTI, etc.)